# Unable to install Intel HAXM on macOS Big Sur

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-emulator, haxm

Just upgraded to Android Studio Bumblbee (2021.1.1 Patch 3) on macOS Big Sur, MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015). Android emulator gone, prompted to install -

[image: Prompt]

Install fails:

[image: Fails]

Android SDK is up to date.
Unable to install Intel® HAXM
HAXM can only be installed on Windows or Mac.
Please file a bug against Android Studio.
Done

What?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this [How to Fix Intel HAXM Android Studio Installation Error on MacOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wnlgKgLaNfA)?

You should try to install the newest version from github --> https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases